# Internet Explorer Not Reloading When Only URL Parameters Changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, url

We have an AngularJS app with a search form. Users have the option in some cases to preset the type of search they want by appending a search type parameter to the URL. This works fine in all browsers except Internet Explorer. It works fine on IE the first time the URL is submitted. But if only the search parameter is changed in the address bar, hitting the Enter button doesn't reload the page.

For instance, if the user puts http://www.domain.com/#!/?searchType=books, the search works in IE. If the user changes it to http://www.domain.com/#!/?searchType=movies and hits the Enter button, nothing happens.

I've tried clearing the cache, telling IE to load all requests directly from the server and tried to force the app to load without using caching. No effect. I've tried to put something in the controller to force the page to reload, but the app doesn't even get far enough to reach the controller's scope. I've also tried to force a reload with javascript in the head of the index.html file and still nothing.

I'm stumped on how to make the app reload on any change in the address in IE.

Comment: You'll need to post a live demo, this could be a million things. What version of IE etc

Comment: The change of URL just need to trigger a reroute in angular, not the refresh of the whole app. Your app need to handle both cases.